paired wilcoxon test in gtsummary for multiple observations per subject
I'm trying to compare two paired samples from 4-period crossover bioequivalence study. My target variable is TMAX (but it may be any other which fits for this test). There are no problems with my code when I left data for only two periods, but the code doesn't work for 4 periods and returns the error.
This is how my data organized, Period variable is ommitted
tmax <- data.frame(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
      Treatment = c("T", "R", "T", "R", "R", "T", "R", "T", "T", "R", "T", "R", "R", "T", "R", "T"), 
      TMAX = c(1.333, 1.667, 0.667, 1.667, 2, 0.667, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0.667, 1, 2, 1))

I tried to use this code (tmax is a df name)
tmax |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = Treatment,
    include = -Subject,
    missing = 'no',
    type = list(TMAX ~ "continuous")
  ) |> 
  add_p(
    test = list(all_continuous() ~ "paired.wilcox.test"
    ),
    group = Subject, pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 3))

Error in lapply(text, glue_cmd, .envir = .envir):
! Could not evaluate cli {} expression: summary_fun.
Caused by error in eval(expr, envir = envir):
! object 'summary_fun' not found
How to resolve this issue?

It doesn't look like your data is appropriate for a single paired Wilcoxon test. This test would expect each subject to have 2 observations, rather than 4.
Regarding the strange error you got: The gtsummary package tries to capture any errors returned when calculating p-values, and message you about them so you can address the underlying issue. In gtsummary v2.0, we updated our messaging to use the {cli} package. By default, the error message strings in cli use glue to evaluate anything in curly brackets. It just so happens that your error/warning contains curly brackets, and cli was trying to evaluate objects that do not exist. Hence the unintelligible error message. We'll update this this in the next release.
FYI, we use this function in the background to calculate your paired test, and you can more clearly see the error messaging.
tmax <- data.frame(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5), 
                   Treatment = c("T", "R", "T", "R", "R", "T", "R", "T", "T", "R", "T", "R", "R", "T", "R", "T"), 
                   TMAX = c(1.333, 1.667, 0.667, 1.667, 2, 0.667, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0.667, 1, 2, 1))

cardx::ard_stats_paired_wilcox_test(
  data = tmax,
  variable = "TMAX",
  by = "Treatment",
  id = "Subject"
)
#> {cards} data frame: 12 x 9
#>       group1 variable   stat_name stat_label  stat   warning     error
#> 1  Treatment     TMAX   statistic  X-square…       Values f… 'x' must…
#> 2  Treatment     TMAX     p.value    p-value       Values f… 'x' must…
#> 3  Treatment     TMAX      method     method       Values f… 'x' must…
#> 4  Treatment     TMAX alternative  alternat…       Values f… 'x' must…
#> 5  Treatment     TMAX          mu         mu     0 Values f… 'x' must…
#> 6  Treatment     TMAX      paired  Paired t…  TRUE Values f… 'x' must…
#> 7  Treatment     TMAX       exact      exact       Values f… 'x' must…
#> 8  Treatment     TMAX     correct    correct  TRUE Values f… 'x' must…
#> 9  Treatment     TMAX    conf.int   conf.int FALSE Values f… 'x' must…
#> 10 Treatment     TMAX  conf.level  CI Confi…  0.95 Values f… 'x' must…
#> 11 Treatment     TMAX    tol.root   tol.root     0 Values f… 'x' must…
#> 12 Treatment     TMAX digits.rank  digits.r…   Inf Values f… 'x' must…
#> ℹ 2 more variables: context, fmt_fn

Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1

Hi, Daniel. Thanks for your clarifications. In my case the problem is in the design - a subject received the same T and the same R twice, so why they are not uniquely identified. My solution was to average 2T and 2R in a single value for each treatment and then pass df to tbl_summary. No errors were returned, the result is as expected :)
